# how to combine and convert two integer columns to datetime lambda c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, .net-core-2.2

i have 2 int column in sql database one for month and one for year
i want to query this against Database like this
DateFrom is dateTime and also DateTo is DataTime

```
   var result = GetAll().Where(x =>
        (x.InvoiceMonth >= DateFrom.Month && x.InvoiceYear >= DateFrom.Year)
                  &&
        (x.InvoiceMonth <= DateTo.Month && x.InvoiceYear <= DateTo.Year));
```

but the problem here if user sent 1/1/2021 to  1/1/2023
it will just return Jan 2021 and Jan 2022and Jan 2023

the correct return should return all things between 2 dates

Comment: you can easily compare `year * 12 + month` ... but .. just add `InvoiceDate` column ....

Comment: Add a proper and indexed date column. It's not enough to use `>= DateFrom.Month && x.InvoiceYear >= DateFrom.Year`. `2023-01` is after `2022-12` even though January is before December

Comment: What is `GetAll()` anyway? Unless it doesn't do what it says, it's loading the entire table into memory. Not a good idea either way - either it loads too much, or an antipattern was used to wrap a high-level ORM under a low-level Data Access Object

Comment: BTW .NET Core 2 reached End Of Life several years ago. The oldest supported version right now is .NET 6. A lot of the problems and hacks used with EF Core 2 are gone now. One of these was client-side evaluation. In EF Core 2, if the ORM couldn't generate a SQL statement, it would load everything in memory and filter it on the client. That's why methods like `GetAll()` didn't seem to cause harm - they did, but that was hidden behind the overall bad performance. Since EF Core 3 client-side evaluation is gone. A proper LINQ query can run 1000s of times faster that in-memory evaluation

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the date with the data you have

```
var result = GetAll().Where(x => 
     (new DateTime(x.InvoiceYear, x.InvoiceMonth, 1) >= 
      new DateTime(DateFrom.InvoiceYear, DateFrom.InvoiceMonth, 1))
              &&
    (new DateTime(x.InvoiceYear, x.InvoiceMonth, 1) <= 
      new DateTime(DateTo.InvoiceYear, DateTo.InvoiceMonth, 1)));
```

Comment: If the application uses an ORM like EF this will force a scan of the entire table to calculate the date values. That's not a problem with this answer itself but the original code